# How to modify XML payload which does not have a parent tag?

Tags: xml, mule, dataweave, mule4

The external API that I am using returns payload as:

```
<code>202</code>
<message>Accepted</message>
```

One example of error response is:

```
<code>401</code>
<message>Unauthorized</message>
```

The problem is this XML does not have a parent tag. So if an error occurs then the expression, **`error.MuleMessage`** throws errors since this is an invalid XML.

Can anyone give me any idea on how to use this response payload?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The input is not a valid XML. You just can't use any XML parser or features to process it.

The ideal solution is to convince the maintainers of that API that it should return valid XML.

A very crude alternative is to add some top element by treating it as a string and concatenating it. This is a hack and not a recommended approach but if you don't have any alternatives:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var s = "<code>202</code><message>Accepted</message>"
var x = read("<root>" ++ s ++ "</root>", "application/xml") // not recommended
---
x.root.code
```

Comment: Thank you for you response. For a success scenario, I am good. The problem is in the error scenario. The expression error.muleMessage will fail which reading payload in XML which eventually fail the error handling logic.

Comment: Please provide more context of the flow that receives that so we can see were it happens.

Comment: Also add  the complete error message and details, and the input received.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but maybe using `error.muleMessage.^raw` does not trigger the DW reader so you don't get the error. To that output, you can append/prepend the root node to read it as XML then https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-selectors

Comment: Technically the content is a well-formed XML entity (sometimes called a "fragment"), but not a well-formed XML document. Some XML parsers have options allowing you to parse a well-formed XML entity. In XSLT 3.0 (or XPath 3.1) you can use the `parse-xml-fragment()` function.

Comment: DataWeave doesn't support fragments, at all. But we need the error to better understand exactly what component is throwing it.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to treat this input as text/plain rather than XML in the HTTP Request operation, then build valid XML. To do this, set the HTTP Request MIME type to 'text/plain'.

In this example, concatenating the root tags to the text input creates a String that can be read as "application/xml". Once read as an Object, the root tag can be removed or otherwise handled as a DW Object.

Although it is a "hack", the fault lies with the source API that is not returning valid XML in the payload.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
    xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core/current/mule-ee.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_config" doc:name="HTTP Listener config"  >
        <http:listener-connection host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" />
    </http:listener-config>
    <flow name="naughtyApi"  >
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="api" outputMimeType="text/plain"/>
        <set-payload value='#[output text/plain&#10;&#10;---&#10;"&lt;code&gt;401&lt;/code&gt;&lt;message&gt;Unauthorized&lt;/message&gt;"]' doc:name="Set Payload" mimeType="application/xml"/>
    </flow>
    <flow name="invokeNaughtyApi" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener"  config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="test"/>
        <http:request method="GET" doc:name="Request" url="http://localhost:8081/api" outputMimeType="text/plain">
            <http:body ><![CDATA[#["null"]]]></http:body>
        </http:request>
        <set-payload value='#[output application/json --- read("&lt;root&gt;" ++ payload as String ++ "&lt;/root&gt;", "application/xml").root]' doc:name="Set Payload"  />
    </flow>
</mule>
```